# Duplicate Identifier in WinJs.d.ts

Tags: javascript, winjs, typescript

I am trying to use TypeScript  in a Windows 8 app (html5/JS)

I have looked at the [sample app](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/deb84dba2fde)

The app uses a typing definition file for WinJS (WinJS.d.ts).

I need to edit this file as it is not complete. However the file has an interface extension for the Type Element adding a property for winControl(typed to any).

This line gets and error of "Duplicate identifier 'winControl'" I am unable to locate and other place this is.

Also, there are locations in my code that i get errors as there is no property named winControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you must

1. remove lib.d.ts from anywhere in your project path (or the path to your **winrt.d.ts**) folder.  It is conflicting with the definitions in your local typescript install folder
2. make sure that you do not have any of your ts (and JS files) identified as content as they will be copied to your deployment directory and will cause the same duplicate issue (there will be two definitions of everything).

I would suggest opening the output window before you do a build.  It will let you see what is causing issues since tcs is being run as a command line behind the scenes for you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same issue that I've experienced when trying to augment the `Window` interface, a bug that is currently being working on:

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/176

However he only mentions `lib.d.ts`, you may want to add your problems to the issue to either make sure that it's also being fixed, or to rule out that this is what causes your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the same issue as the WinJS.d.ts is extending the Element interface from the lib.d.ts